# Can't access ambari UI

Tags: hadoop, authentication, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to use Hadoop. Unfortunately, I cannot access the Ambari login. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some other web server running on port 8080 for Apache + Postgres

Also, the link in the VM says `1080`. Can you get there? Can you access the other UI's on the HDP quickstart dashboard? If so, then Ambari isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I can't access the link with 1080 in Chrome or Edge, it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. If some other web server is running on port 8080, what should I do to solve this? Does it have something to do with port forwarding? Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: You can open the port forwarding settings in vbox to check which port Ambari would be on. I'm not actually sure what port 1080 is... I've not used the sandbox in several years

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: The port was blocked by postgresql, so I stopped postgresql and it worked.